# Get custom text from a custom web part property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-studio-2013

I would to display text entered in a custom web part property onto a form.

This code is to display the custom web part property

```
 [WebBrowsable(true),
     Category("Miscellaneous"),
     Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
     WebDisplayName("Enter some text")]
     public string CustomTextProp { get; set; }
```

This is the div to display what was entered in the code above

```
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">TEXT USER ENTERED IN WEB PART PROPERTIES</div>
```

My question is how to I get the text the user entered in the web part property to display in the div?

Comment: should it be showed after saving or right when tiping in?

Comment: It should be showed after saving

Comment: and where is this div located?

Comment: UserItemDisplay.ascx

Comment: is this a control you created?

Comment: Yes it is a control.

Comment: is it in the web part you are editing?

Comment: Say I edit the webpart and enters the text. I save it. it then displays on a form. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: why do you do that in the webpart properties? seems a bit complicated to me. why not in the webpart properites of that form?

Comment: Would that give the same result? could you maybe elaborate what you mean?

Comment: maybe I missunderstood. do you display the form in the webpart you are editing the properties of?

Comment: yes I display the form in the web part that I edit

Comment: does it need to be a div or is it possible to use a asp:Label Element?

Comment: Does not matter. Thats what I though would be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a Label and in the onLoad method of your webpart you can access this label and write the value of the saved property to its Text.Field.

Or you could in the set-Method of the Property set the .Text of the Label to the value entered to the WebPart Property;

Tell me if you need more help.